# how to get the value of Input.Password item in antd

Tags: javascript, antd

Now I am design a password change UI in my system, I write the change passowd UI like this:

```
const ChangePwd = () => (
            <Form
                {...layout}
                name='changepwd'
                
                onFinish={onFinish}
                onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
                onFinishFailed={onFinishFailed}>
                <Form.Item
                    label='old password'
                    name='oldpassword'
                    rules={[
                        {
                            required: true,
                            message: 'Please input your username!'
                        }
                    ]}>
                    <Input />
                </Form.Item>

                <Form.Item
                    label='new password'
                    name='newpassword'
                    rules={[
                        {
                            required: true,
                            message: 'Please input your password!'
                        }
                    ]}>
                    <Input.Password />
                </Form.Item>

                <Form.Item
                    label='repeat pasword'
                    name='newpasswordrepeat'
                    rules={[
                        {
                            required: true,
                            message: 'Please input your password!'
                        }
                    ]}>
                    <Input.Password />
                </Form.Item>

                <Form.Item {...tailLayout}>
                    <Button type='primary' htmlType='submit'>
                        submit
                    </Button>
                </Form.Item>
            </Form>
        )
```

I want to get the value of password and send to backend, what should I get the value of the user input? Now I am doing it like this but could not get the value of user input:

```
  handleSubmit = (values) => {
        let { oldpassword, newpassword } = values
        if (newpassword !== oldpassword) {
            alert('new password not equal to old')
            return
        }
        let user = localStorage.getItem("user");
        var request = {
            phone: user.phone,
            oldPassword: oldpassword,
            newPassword: newpassword
        }
        modifyPassword(request)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

use the onchange event:

```
  <Input.Password value={this.state.oldPassword} onChange={this.handleOldPasswordChange} />
```

and get the user input like this:

```
handleOldPasswordChange = e => {
        if (this.state.oldPassword !== e.target.value) {
            this.setState({
                oldPassword: e.target.value
            })
        }
    }
```

works.